# Swiftui Preview Crashing using Navigationstack (Problem Report included)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I can't figure out why my preview is crashing each time I press the "Hello World" text. I have a programatically navigationstack setup, and each time a view is appended it crashes in the preview. The app on my phone works great though, but I thought I must be doing something wrong if the preview is messing up. Thanks!

Here is the problem report:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 980494AC-44F1-43DF-B8BE-AB6FAA94E7A7
CrashReporter Key:   2F1EEC48-C1DA-2145-0171-733D5994FA2F
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir9,1
Process:             Previewtest [88699]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices/B5B42958-9616-46D6-A056-B44D3D125005/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E4B38613-49C2-4582-9650-7295F743C525/Previewtest.app/Previewtest
Identifier:          Partyhallen.Previewtest
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [87351]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.B5B42958-9616-46D6-A056-B44D3D125005 [11821]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [2117]

Date/Time:           2022-12-03 00:13:50.6532 +0100
Launch Time:         2022-12-03 00:13:49.4824 +0100
OS Version:          macOS 12.6 (21G115)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process: exc handler [88699]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x7ff80d700cc8 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 424
1   SwiftUI                                0x10d6c9ed8 0x10c316000 + 20659928
2   SwiftUI                                0x10d6c9de5 0x10c316000 + 20659685
3   Previewtest                            0x1081105ab ContentView.router.getter + 139
4   ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib          0x10e4b761e closure #1 in closure #1 in ContentView.__preview__body.getter + 30 (ContentView.swift:13)
5   SwiftUI                                0x10c7fc79d 0x10c316000 + 5138333
6   SwiftUI                                0x10d08588a 0x10c316000 + 14088330
7   SwiftUI                                0x10cded270 0x10c316000 + 11367024
8   SwiftUI                                0x10cded284 0x10c316000 + 11367044
9   SwiftUI                                0x10cded270 0x10c316000 + 11367024
10  SwiftUI                                0x10cb03491 0x10c316000 + 8311953
11  SwiftUI                                0x10cb02df2 0x10c316000 + 8310258
12  SwiftUI                                0x10cc947a5 0x10c316000 + 9955237
13  SwiftUI                                0x10d4437c8 0x10c316000 + 18012104
14  SwiftUI                                0x10d441e5e 0x10c316000 + 18005598
15  SwiftUI                                0x10d441f42 0x10c316000 + 18005826
16  SwiftUI                                0x10d441720 0x10c316000 + 18003744
17  UIKitCore                              0x1090274b9 -[UIGestureRecognizer _componentsEnded:withEvent:] + 153
18  UIKitCore                              0x1096c6ebd -[UITouchesEvent _sendEventToGestureRecognizer:] + 662
19  UIKitCore                              0x1090176f7 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:] + 469
20  UIKitCore                              0x109669edb -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 5282
21  UIKitCore                              0x10963d7f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 898
22  UIKitCore                              0x1096e4e61 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 9381
23  UIKitCore                              0x1096e7569 __processEventQueue + 8334
24  UIKitCore                              0x1096dd8a1 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 272
25  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800387035 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
26  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800386f74 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
27  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800386771 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
28  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800380e73 __CFRunLoopRun + 927
29  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003806f7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
30  GraphicsServices                    0x7ff809c5c28a GSEventRunModal + 139
31  UIKitCore                              0x10961c62b -[UIApplication _run] + 994
32  UIKitCore                              0x109621547 UIApplicationMain + 123
33  SwiftUI                                0x10d3fbcfb 0x10c316000 + 17718523
34  SwiftUI                                0x10d3fbba8 0x10c316000 + 17718184
35  SwiftUI                                0x10cab1b7d 0x10c316000 + 7977853
36  Previewtest                            0x108112d4e static PreviewtestApp.$main() + 30 (PreviewtestApp.swift:4)
37  Previewtest                            0x108112e09 main + 9
38  dyld_sim                               0x1083662bf start_sim + 10
39  dyld                                   0x11476f52e start + 462

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff834c38f48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff834c38f48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff834c38f48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff834c38f48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff834c38f48 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff834bdf97a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff834bdfce8 mach_msg + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003868de __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
3   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80038102f __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003806f7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
5   Foundation                          0x7ff800c5595c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 213
6   Foundation                          0x7ff800c55bd5 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 72
7   UIKitCore                              0x1096f0886 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 535
8   Foundation                          0x7ff800c7f1c3 __NSThread__start__ + 1009
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff834c3d4e1 _pthread_start + 125
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff834c38f6b thread_start + 15


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000200000003  rbx: 0x000000010d6ff670  rcx: 0xfffffffe00000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000003
  rdi: 0x00007f7959c0f888  rsi: 0x000000000000001b  rbp: 0x00007ff7b7def100  rsp: 0x00007ff7b7def0b0
   r8: 0x0000000000000071   r9: 0x0000000000000070  r10: 0x0000000000000f30  r11: 0x0000600001a61aa8
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000046  r14: 0x00007f7959c0f880  r15: 0x000000000000000b
  rip: 0x00007ff80d700cc8  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x000000012793b000
  
Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000000 
Trap Number:     6


Binary Images:
    0x7ff80d6d4000 -     0x7ff80db90ff4 libswiftCore.dylib (*) <1d23cd50-8b48-349b-9163-f7990e0f95bd> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
       0x10c316000 -        0x10d9eefff com.apple.SwiftUI (4.1.17.100) <1622c162-0a3a-354c-94ea-62c5dd369612> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
       0x10810c000 -        0x108113fff Partyhallen.Previewtest (1.0) <a989b4b0-9e28-34db-865c-bbcabac9f176> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator Devices/B5B42958-9616-46D6-A056-B44D3D125005/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E4B38613-49C2-4582-9650-7295F743C525/Previewtest.app/Previewtest
       0x10e4b5000 -        0x10e4b8fff ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib (*) <5d91714e-5553-3450-88be-8850c5896cb4> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Previewtest-haqnqqxsierjlvhdmnfotfqgnorc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/Previewtest/Intermediates.noindex/Previewtest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Previewtest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib
       0x1087e1000 -        0x10a29dfff com.apple.UIKitCore (1.0) <c2258b63-cdcc-3504-a06e-8067adba9c34> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
    0x7ff800302000 -     0x7ff80068affc com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <55edff37-af14-3fed-b932-031049d0a665> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x7ff809c59000 -     0x7ff809c60ff2 com.apple.GraphicsServices (1.0) <5dad91c5-e70d-3f9a-88f2-2d1ed7c8dd24> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x108364000 -        0x1083c3fff dyld_sim (*) <638f8a1f-2a32-396d-8389-8d7a60b96b8d> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim
       0x11476a000 -        0x1147d5fff dyld (*) <71febccd-d9dc-3599-9971-2b3407c588a8> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7ff834c37000 -     0x7ff834c42ff7 libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <b5454e27-e8c7-3fdb-b77f-714f1e82e70b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7ff834bde000 -     0x7ff834c15fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <8cc28466-fd2f-3c80-9834-9525b7beac19> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7ff8006fd000 -     0x7ff80102dffc com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <353e6739-fc3a-3636-89f2-194adba7203b> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

EOF

-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"Previewtest","timestamp":"2022-12-03 00:13:51.00 +0100","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"a989b4b0-9e28-34db-865c-bbcabac9f176","build_version":"1","platform":7,"bundleID":"Partyhallen.Previewtest","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.6 (21G115)","incident_id":"980494AC-44F1-43DF-B8BE-AB6FAA94E7A7","name":"Previewtest"}
{
  "uptime" : 370000,
  "procLaunch" : "2022-12-03 00:13:49.4824 +0100",
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookAir9,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 374779515462303,
  "coalitionID" : 11821,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.6",
    "build" : "21G115",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-12-03 00:13:50.6532 +0100",
  "incident" : "980494AC-44F1-43DF-B8BE-AB6FAA94E7A7",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 88699,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 374780663063696,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "procName" : "Previewtest",
  "procPath" : "\/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/UserData\/Previews\/Simulator Devices\/B5B42958-9616-46D6-A056-B44D3D125005\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/E4B38613-49C2-4582-9650-7295F743C525\/Previewtest.app\/Previewtest",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0","CFBundleVersion":"1","CFBundleIdentifier":"Partyhallen.Previewtest"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"B5E785AA-2399-55A2-8DC1-FCE60C089E4D","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd_sim",
  "parentPid" : 87351,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.B5B42958-9616-46D6-A056-B44D3D125005",
  "crashReporterKey" : "2F1EEC48-C1DA-2145-0171-733D5994FA2F",
  "responsiblePid" : 2117,
  "responsibleProc" : "SimulatorTrampoline",
  "wakeTime" : 5437,
  "bridgeVersion" : {"build":"19P6067","train":"6.6"},
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "407BF33E-E77C-46C9-BE09-2761B3AEE27C",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[1,0],"type":"EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION","signal":"SIGILL"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":4,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Illegal instruction: 4","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":88699},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":28},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":4314897,"instructionState":{"instructionStream":{"bytes":[184,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,73,133,196,15,132,198,1,0,0,72,131,192,255,76,137,247,72,33,199,72,131,199,32,72,184,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,73,33,196,72,131,236,8,68,15,182,69,24,76,137,230,72,139,85,208,72,139,77,16,73,137,217,69,49,228,139,69,40,80,65,85,65,87,232,20,18,0,0,72,131,196,32,76,137,247,232,56,65,52,0,15,11,72,131,236,8,72,141,5,251,241,69,0,72,141,61,184,237,69,0,72,141,13,205,240,69,0,190,11,0,0,0,65,184,57,0,0,0,186,2,0,0,0,65,185,2,0,0,0,106,0,104,148,0,0,0,106,2,106,24,80,232,182,2,0,0,72,131,236,8,72,141,5,203,237,69,0,72,141,61,120,237,69,0,72,141,13,141,237,69,0,190,11,0,0,0],"offset":96}},"threadState":{"r13":{"value":70},"rax":{"value":8589934595},"rflags":{"value":66118},"cpu":{"value":1},"r14":{"value":140159173589120},"rsi":{"value":27},"r8":{"value":113},"cr2":{"value":4958957568},"rdx":{"value":3},"r10":{"value":3888},"r9":{"value":112},"r15":{"value":11},"rbx":{"value":4520408688},"trap":{"value":6},"err":{"value":0},"r11":{"value":105553143929512},"rip":{"value":140703354064072,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"rbp":{"value":140701918490880},"rsp":{"value":140701918490800},"r12":{"value":0},"rcx":{"value":18446744065119617024},"flavor":"x86_THREAD_STATE","rdi":{"value":140159173589128}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":183496,"symbol":"_assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:)","symbolLocation":424,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":20659928,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":20659685,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":17835,"sourceFile":"ContentView.swift","symbol":"ContentView.router.getter","symbolLocation":139,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":9758,"sourceLine":13,"sourceFile":"ContentView.swift","symbol":"closure #1 in closure #1 in ContentView.__preview__body.getter","imageIndex":3,"symbolLocation":30},{"imageOffset":5138333,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":14088330,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":11367024,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":11367044,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":11367024,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8311953,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8310258,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":9955237,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18012104,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18005598,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18005826,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":18003744,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8676537,"symbol":"-[UIGestureRecognizer _componentsEnded:withEvent:]","symbolLocation":153,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15621821,"symbol":"-[UITouchesEvent _sendEventToGestureRecognizer:]","symbolLocation":662,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":8611575,"symbol":"-[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:]","symbolLocation":469,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15240923,"symbol":"-[UIWindow sendEvent:]","symbolLocation":5282,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15058930,"symbol":"-[UIApplication sendEvent:]","symbolLocation":898,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15744609,"symbol":"__dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue","symbolLocation":9381,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15754601,"symbol":"__processEventQueue","symbolLocation":8334,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":15714465,"symbol":"__eventFetcherSourceCallback","symbolLocation":272,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":544821,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__","symbolLocation":17,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":544628,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSource0","symbolLocation":157,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":542577,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopDoSources0","symbolLocation":212,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":519795,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":927,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":517879,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":560,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":12938,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":139,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":14923307,"symbol":"-[UIApplication _run]","symbolLocation":994,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":14943559,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":123,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":17718523,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":17718184,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":7977853,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":27982,"sourceLine":4,"sourceFile":"PreviewtestApp.swift","symbol":"static PreviewtestApp.$main()","imageIndex":2,"symbolLocation":30},{"imageOffset":28169,"sourceFile":"PreviewtestApp.swift","symbol":"main","symbolLocation":9,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":8895,"symbol":"start_sim","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":21806,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":462,"imageIndex":8}]},{"id":4314907,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8008,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":9}]},{"id":4314908,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8008,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":9}]},{"id":4314909,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8008,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":9}]},{"id":4314910,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8008,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":9}]},{"id":4314911,"frames":[{"imageOffset":8008,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":9}]},{"id":4314912,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":6522,"symbol":"mach_msg_trap","symbolLocation":10,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":7400,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":542942,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":145,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":520239,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1371,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":517879,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":560,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":5605724,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]","symbolLocation":213,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":5606357,"symbol":"-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]","symbolLocation":72,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":15792262,"symbol":"-[UIEventFetcher threadMain]","symbolLocation":535,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":5775811,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":1009,"imageIndex":11},{"imageOffset":25825,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":125,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":8043,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":15,"imageIndex":9}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703353880576,
    "size" : 4968437,
    "uuid" : "1d23cd50-8b48-349b-9163-f7990e0f95bd",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime\/Contents\/Resources\/RuntimeRoot\/usr\/lib\/swift\/libswiftCore.dylib",
    "name" : "libswiftCore.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4499529728,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "4.1.17.100",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.SwiftUI",
    "size" : 23957504,
    "uuid" : "1622c162-0a3a-354c-94ea-62c5dd369612",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime\/Contents\/Resources\/RuntimeRoot\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/SwiftUI.framework\/SwiftUI",
    "name" : "SwiftUI",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "4.1.17.100"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4430282752,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "Partyhallen.Previewtest",
    "size" : 32768,
    "uuid" : "a989b4b0-9e28-34db-865c-bbcabac9f176",
    "path" : "\/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/UserData\/Previews\/Simulator Devices\/B5B42958-9616-46D6-A056-B44D3D125005\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/E4B38613-49C2-4582-9650-7295F743C525\/Previewtest.app\/Previewtest",
    "name" : "Previewtest",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4534784000,
    "size" : 16384,
    "uuid" : "5d91714e-5553-3450-88be-8850c5896cb4",
    "path" : "\/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/Xcode\/DerivedData\/Previewtest-haqnqqxsierjlvhdmnfotfqgnorc\/Build\/Intermediates.noindex\/Previews\/Previewtest\/Intermediates.noindex\/Previewtest.build\/Debug-iphonesimulator\/Previewtest.build\/Objects-normal\/x86_64\/ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib",
    "name" : "ContentView.1.preview-thunk.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4437446656,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.UIKitCore",
    "size" : 28037120,
    "uuid" : "c2258b63-cdcc-3504-a06e-8067adba9c34",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime\/Contents\/Resources\/RuntimeRoot\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/UIKitCore.framework\/UIKitCore",
    "name" : "UIKitCore",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "6109.1.108"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703131770880,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.CoreFoundation",
    "size" : 3706877,
    "uuid" : "55edff37-af14-3fed-b932-031049d0a665",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime\/Contents\/Resources\/RuntimeRoot\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1953.1"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703292559360,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.GraphicsServices",
    "size" : 32755,
    "uuid" : "5dad91c5-e70d-3f9a-88f2-2d1ed7c8dd24",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime\/Contents\/Resources\/RuntimeRoot\/System\/Library\/PrivateFrameworks\/GraphicsServices.framework\/GraphicsServices",
    "name" : "GraphicsServices",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1.0"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4432740352,
    "size" : 393216,
    "uuid" : "638f8a1f-2a32-396d-8389-8d7a60b96b8d",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime\/Contents\/Resources\/RuntimeRoot\/usr\/lib\/dyld_sim",
    "name" : "dyld_sim"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 4638285824,
    "size" : 442368,
    "uuid" : "71febccd-d9dc-3599-9971-2b3407c588a8",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140704013840384,
    "size" : 49144,
    "uuid" : "b5454e27-e8c7-3fdb-b77f-714f1e82e70b",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140704013475840,
    "size" : 229376,
    "uuid" : "8cc28466-fd2f-3c80-9834-9525b7beac19",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "x86_64",
    "base" : 140703135944704,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "6.9",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.Foundation",
    "size" : 9637885,
    "uuid" : "353e6739-fc3a-3636-89f2-194adba7203b",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime\/Contents\/Resources\/RuntimeRoot\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/Foundation.framework\/Foundation",
    "name" : "Foundation",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "1953.1"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 140703128616960,
  "size" : 2998861824,
  "uuid" : "3140e7f6-3cc2-3fac-81dd-5fbfbbe796e1"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=803.7M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=803.7M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=575.2M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=575.2M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nCG raster data                       8K        1 \nColorSync                           88K        5 \nCoreAnimation                       20K        1 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 \nMALLOC                           177.5M       30 \nMALLOC guard page                   32K        8 \nMALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nSTACK GUARD                       56.0M        7 \nStack                             11.0M        7 \nVM_ALLOCATE                       1052K        4 \n__DATA                            11.3M      398 \n__DATA_CONST                      36.7M      402 \n__DATA_DIRTY                        26K       12 \n__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       358.0M       33 \n__OBJC_RO                         28.3M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                          880K        1 \n__TEXT                           445.8M      410 \ndyld private memory               1280K        2 \nmapped file                      206.8M       11 \nshared memory                       16K        1 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.7G     1339 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.3G     1339 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "63582c5f8a53461413999550",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000002
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60f8ddccefea4203d95cbeef",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000021
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

@main
struct PreviewtestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppContainerView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct AppContainerView: View {
    @StateObject var router = Router()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.navigationPath) {
            ContentView()
                .navigationDestination(for: Route.self) { route in
                    switch route {
                    case .ContentView:
                        ContentView()
                    }
                }
        }.environmentObject(router)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var router: Router
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .onTapGesture {
                    router.pushView(route: .ContentView)
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

enum Route: Hashable {
    case ContentView
}

final class Router: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navigationPath = NavigationPath()
    
    func pushView(route: Route) {
        navigationPath.append(route)
    }
    
    func popToRootView() {
        navigationPath = .init()
    }
    
    func popToSpecificView(k: Int) {
        navigationPath.removeLast(k)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@StateObject` aren't init during previewing so that is probably causing the crash. You could workaround it by previewing `AppContainerView` instead of `ContentView`.

By the way, `@StateObject` is for when you need to store a reference type in a `@State` but in this example don't need a reference type. Also, `NavigationPath` is designed to hold the data values, not routes. You can use multiple `navigationDestination` for each kind of value, instead of one with a switch statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and the advice about navigationdestination/switch. Problem solved!